# Objective-C cheat sheet

Tags: objective-c

What cheat sheets exist for Objective-C?

I have googled but I really don't know what to look for. Most of them assume I know Objective-C and I don't.  I really want a guide aimed at an experienced programmer.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The Apple developer site has <s>[Introduction to The Objective-C 2.0 Programming Language](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Introduction/introObjectiveC.html)</s> *(dead link)*

[A 10-Minute Introduction to Objective-C](http://www.geom.uiuc.edu/software/w3kit/overview/objective-c.html)

[The Ultimate iPhone Objective-C Cheat Sheet](http://maniacdev.com/2009/04/the-ultimate-iphone-objective-c-cheat-sheet/)

<s>[Objective-C Cheat Sheet](http://www.dzone.com/links/rss/objectivec_cheat_sheet.html)</s> *(dead link)*

<s>[Objective-C Cheat Sheet](http://the-lazy-programmer.com/blog/files/Objective-C%20cheat%20sheet.pdf) (pdf)</s> *(dead link)*

Comment: Thanks so much, those are all excellent!

Comment: The last two links don't work (no cheat sheet there).

Comment: @splattne: that's because this is an old post and the internet changes ;)

Answer (score 1):

Here is another cheat sheet which compares C, C++, Objective-C and C#. Useful if you're coming from one of the other "C-like" languages.

[Platform Languages: C, C++, Objective C, Java, C# a side-by-side reference sheet](http://hyperpolyglot.org/cpp)