# Is there a guide or cheat sheet somewhere that I can reference all the syntax of objective c?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, ios

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Objective-C cheat sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/823672/objective-c-cheat-sheet)

Is there a guide or cheat sheet somewhere that I can reference all the syntax of objective c?

I'd also like to see cheat sheets that you might have liked or would have liked when you started dev-ing in objective c.

```
@synthesize window;
#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Application lifecycle
@implementation OpenAlTestingAppDelegate
```

PS. I've looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/823672/objective-c-cheat-sheet), and it seems to be out of date.

Comment: The first three links on the first answer to the question you linked to are all still relevant and working.

Answer (score 2):

Yes there is.  [Here is one](http://maniacdev.com/2009/04/the-ultimate-iphone-objective-c-cheat-sheet/).  It seems relatively comprehensive to me.

By the way, that was the top hit from Googling [Objective-C cheat sheet](http://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=objective-c%20cheat%20sheet&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8).

Comment: http://maniacdev.com/2009/04/the-ultimate-iphone-objective-c-cheat-sheet/ -- Was also on the question I linked. :)

Comment: +1 for the link, but after looking at it I really have to wonder how useful it could possibly be. Most of the items there are about 97% conceptual and 3% syntax. If you don't understand what messaging is, having a sheet that shows you the syntax isn't going to help. If you do understand it, remembering the syntax shouldn't be a problem, and there are examples everywhere you look. Same goes for things like class and protocol declarations, 'self', etc.

Comment: @jbcurtin, @Caleb: That's why I also linked the Google search.  There are loads of cheat sheets, even an app.

Comment: @Caleb: No cheat sheet in the World is going to teach you how to program in Objective-C.  Cheat sheets are there to help you with things like syntax.

Comment: I agree. I'm just pointing out that if you understand Objective-C messaging, you're not likely to forget that messages are contained in square brackets or that the receiver goes on the left and the message on the right.

Answer (score 1):

Honestly when I was starting with Objective-C I found the [wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Objective_c) on the subject to be a great help.  I don't know if it covers all of the syntax or if it can be considered a "cheat sheet", but it certainly helped me get up to speed with the basics of the language and its syntax quickly.

Answer (score 1):

The one at http://hyperpolyglot.org/c is nifty because it compares syntax for five different C-based languages: C, C++, Objective-C, Java, and C#. I think this one could actually be useful if you already know one or more of the languages listed and are just trying to pick up one of the others. It won't make you an expert overnight, but this and a couple nights at Holiday Inn Express could point you in the right direction.